# Process exited with return value 3221226356 when system("cls") is written. (SOLVED)

Tags: c++, oop, pointers

I am making a snake game in console, but whenever I write system("cls") in draw function it writes "Process exited with return value 3221226356" on Output screen.
I think there is some memory leak but I couldn't find the exact reason why this is happening.

You can also see this code at: https://github.com/Lakshay-Dhingra/Snake-Game

Here's my code:  //Compiled in Dev-C++(Windows) with mingw std-c++11 compiler

```
    #include<iostream>
    #include<conio.h>
    #include <unistd.h>
    #include<cstdlib>
    using namespace std;
    
    class Node
    {
        int x;
        int y;
        Node *link;
        
        public:
        Node(int ix,int iy)
        {
            x=ix;
            y=iy;
            link=nullptr;
        }
        
        int getx()
        {
            return x;
        }
        void setx(int x)
        {
            this->x=x;
        }
        int gety()
        {
            return y;
        }
        void sety(int y)
        {
            this->y=y;
        }
        
        Node* getLink()
        {
            return link;
        }
        void setLink(Node* x)
        {
            link=x;
        }
    };
    
    class LL
    {
        public:
        Node* head;
        LL()
        {
            head=nullptr;
        }
        
        void insert(int x,int y)
        {
            Node* mynode=new Node(x,y);
            Node* temp=head;
            head=mynode;
            head->setLink(temp);
        }   

    int* show(int l)
        {
            int* arr=new int(2*l);
            int i=0;
            Node* cur=head;
            while(cur!=nullptr)
            {
                arr[i]=cur->getx();
                arr[i+1]=cur->gety();
                i+=2;
                cur=cur->getLink();
            }
            return arr;
        }
    
    

    ~LL()
        {
            Node* temp=head;
            while(head!=nullptr)
            {
                temp=head->getLink();
                delete head;
                head=temp;
            }
        }
    };
    
    class Snake
    {
        int length;
        LL* mysnake;
        
        public:
        Snake(int l,int x,int y)
        {
            mysnake=new LL();
            for(int i=0;i<l;i++)
            {
                mysnake->insert((x+i),y);
            }
            length=l;
        }
        
        int getLength()
        {
            return length;
        }
        
        void eatFood(int x,int y)
        {
            length+=1;
            mysnake->insert(x,y);
        }
        
        int* showSnake()
        {
            return mysnake->show(length);
        }
        
        int getHeadX()
        {
            return mysnake->head->getx();
        }
        int getHeadY()
        {
            return mysnake->head->gety();
        }
    };
    
    class Window
    {
        int length;
        int hieght;
        Snake* snk;
        int* arr;
        
        public:
        Window(int l,int h,int posx,int posy)
        {
            
            length=l;
            hieght=h;
            snk=new Snake(4,posx-3,posy);
            arr=snk->showSnake();
        }
        
        void rungame()
        {
            char ch;
            while(true)
            {
                if(kbhit())
                {
                ch = _getch();
                if(int(ch)==27)
                    break;
                }
                draw();
            }
        }
        
        void draw()
        {
            system("cls");
            bool flag;
            for(int i=0;i<length;i++)
            {
                for(int j=0;j<hieght;j++)
                {
                    flag=0;
                    if(i==0||i==length-1||j==0||j==hieght-1)
                    {
                        cout<<"#";
                        flag=1;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        for(int k=0;k<snk->getLength();k++)
                        {
                            if(i==arr[2*k]&&j==arr[2*k+1])
                            {
                                cout<<"O";
                                flag=1;
                            }
                        }
                    }
    
                    if(flag==0)
                    {
                        cout<<" ";
                    }
                }
                cout<<endl;
            }
            usleep(100000);
        }
    };
    
    int main()
    {
        Window win(30,50,15,25);
        win.rungame();
        return 0;
    }
```

Issue:

```
    int* show(int l)
        {
            int* arr=new int(2*l);
            // Above line was causing the issue
            // It was a small silly mistake where I used round brackets
            // instead of square brackets
            // My program was treating arr as array which was causing memory leak
```

Comment: Please create a [mre] instead of dumping all your code.

Comment: Your `showSnake` method allocates an array and never frees it, but I do not think this is the cause for the crash. Attach a debugger and inspect the crash site.

Comment: Consider using a library such as [ncurses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses) or learn about [ANSI escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error 3221226356 is 0xc0000374 in hex, which is STATUS_HEAP_CORRUPTION.

I missed it on my first read-through, but it is caused by your allocation in `show()`:

```
int* arr=new int(2*l);
```

This allocates spaces for a *single* `int` and fills it with the value `2*l`. You subsequently write to unallocated/uninitialized memory: `arr[1]`, `arr[2]`, and so on.

The immediate fix is simple:

```
int* arr = new int[2*l];
```

This allocates space for `2*l` `int` values.

In the long run you are better off using a `std::vector<int>` instead, or foregoing this whole array business and walking your linked list directly when you need to (in your `draw` function, for example).

Answer (score 1):

`unistd.h` is a UNIX header (Linux, MacOS, etc...), you shouldn't include it in a Windows project. That can be the reason.

The call is `system("clear");` in a Linux SO.

You then have to replace functions like `usleep()` that belongs to `unistd.h` and is not usable in a Windows project.

I believe `windows.h` has some similar functions.